# MongoDB Authentication in a Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I'm trying to set up authentication in a sharded cluster. Currently all shards, config servers and mongos are running without `--auth` or keyfile information.

when I'm connecting to `mongo` and trying to create user:

```
db.createUser({
  user: "test",
  pwd: "test",
  roles: []
});
```

i get the following error:

> Error: couldn't add user: Could not lock auth data update lock. at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Start all of the components of the cluster with --auth first. See [Enable Authentication in a Sharded Cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-in-sharded-cluster/).

Comment: tried this to. get the same error. but the Mongo docs is saying something different:
"If users exist in the MongoDB database, but none of them has the appropriate prerequisites to create a new user or you do not have access to them, you must restart mongod  with the --noauth option"

Comment: So do you have users already in there or not?

Comment: I had local users in the config servers (inserted directly to each config server), I guess that's why I couldn't insert new users through Mongos. I've remove all config servers and re-created them, it worked. thanks!